# Discord.PY JSON

Tags: json, discord.py

So I was working on something and weird things are happening. My amounts.json is resetting and the code isn't adding to the amounts.json. (ex. I type the command that adds to the number and it does nothing to the amounts.json)

Code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def redeem(ctx, key):
    with open('amounts.json') as f:
     amounts = json.load(f)
    id = int(ctx.message.author.id)
    if key in amounts:
      if amounts[key] < int(2):
       await ctx.send("You have been given Buyer role!")
       amounts[key] += int(1)
       member = ctx.message.author
       this_guild = member.guild

       role = get(member.guild.roles, name='Buyer')
       await member.add_roles(role)
       Message = ctx.message
       await Message.delete()
       await ctx.send("You have been given Buyer role!")
       _save()
      else:
        await ctx.send("Invalid Key!")

    else:
        await ctx.send("Invalid Key!")
```

JSON

```
{"196430670": 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving your JSON file back, based on the edited `amounts` dict.

Comment: I think I am. I am calling _save and it does this.                                                        ```def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)```